# External Website href on Facebook PHP SDK notification

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want my notification to redirect to my site. For example, if someone clicks on a notification, it will take him to the relevant page in my website.

Let's say I want to redirect people to google.com:

```
$app_access_token = $app_id . '|' . $app_secret;

$notifID = '{user-id}';
$notifHREF = 'http://google.com';
$notifTEMPLATE = 'go to google';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $app_id,
    'app_secret' => $app_secret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$request = $fb->request('POST', "/$notifID/notifications?access_token=$app_access_token&href=$notifHREF&template=$notifTEMPLATE");
```

When the user gets the notification and clicks it, he won't see http://google.com but this page: `https://apps.facebook.com/{app-id}//?fb_source=notification`.

Is there any way to redirect the `href` to an external website?
Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far? how about checking out the facebook docs and doing some testing?

Comment: @luschn i think it's pretty obvious i tried before asking here. I just can't understand how can I do thing with FB PHP SDK when the user logged in using the Javascript SDK.

Comment: to be honest, it is not obvious. why not just use the same access token? what did you try?

Comment: @luschn that's the thing - how do I get that token? the user logged in using javascript sdk, so the token is not accessible. correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: afaik you just need an app access token for that. so you don´t even need to transfer any token from client to server. and why would a token not be accessible if the user logged in using the js sdk?

Comment: yeah, but in order to use the facebook requests, api call and such, I have to have the user access token. see, I just tried to use the PHP code from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_access_token_from_javascript). It works if I have just logged in, but if the user is a returning user it won't work. and will say `Graph returned an error: This authorization code has expired.`.

Comment: no, as you can read in my answer and in the docs, notifications are sent with an app token, not a user token

Comment: either way, you CAN get the user token with the js sdk, and you CAN send it to the server. it´s not neccessary in this case though.

Comment: _“I want my notification to redirect to my site”_ – you are not allowed to do that. Notifications take the user to canvas, and you have to present relevant content there. Using canvas for the sole purpose of redirecting people outside of Facebook is not allowed. When Facebook catches you doing that, they will disable your app.

Comment: @CBroe is there any alternatives for that? I had this idea in my mind becuase I remember that in the Comments Plugin you do get a notification that redirects you to the website..

Answer (score 1):

> Apps can generate notifications by issuing a HTTP POST request to the /user_id/notifications Graph API, with an **app access_token**.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications#implementation

...so you don´t even need to deal with sending Tokens from client to server as it´s a static one per App. Just use the App Token with an App Scoped User ID.

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: What do you mean by `App Scoped User ID`? and thanks!

Comment: Oh I see! I almost forgot what i'm trying to do. How can I send that POST request? seems like I do need a session variable, as they did [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post)

Comment: post request: google for "php curl" - or use the php sdk. no clue why you would need a session variable...what for? what do you want to store?

Comment: @AvielShomron those examples are outdated, the PHP SDK v5 doesn’t use a session any more. Go check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted for up-to-date examples.